# SPAM deluge over at WebApps (and pretty much all over SE)

Tags: support, spam

> Related: **[Recent Mass Football Spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam)**

[Web Applications's newest questions page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) is currently football-SPAM ridden to a surprising degree.

Anything ordinary community members can/should do when something like this happens (apart from draining their SPAM flag quota)? Any way to notify someone/thing to accelerate the purge?

> [image]

Update: The network is fighting back apparently. Network-wide, year-long suspensions have been handed out to some of the spam accounts.

> [image]
>   [image]

Comment: I'm going to drain my flag spam quota for now

Comment: Yay, that was fun. Out of spam flags now.

Comment: wow... the call to arms seems effective

Comment: Thanks everyone! That front page looks clean now. Also this [search on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=tv) currently hits on SPAM a lot.

Comment: Since I had to create a new account on Web Apps first, I got to be the last one to cast the spam flag on several of those questions. And boy was that exhilarating! No "thanks for your input" noise, the page just immediately refreshed and told me that the question had been "removed for reasons of moderation". BAM! Done.

Comment: @Mat I have spotted and flagged two on SO, and seems pretty clean on first scan. got to go now, sorry

Comment: P.s. could you next time clearly indicate in your screenshot what you are referring to? It was rather unclear to me which posts were spam. It was only at second glance that I noticed the subtle indications you put in.

Comment: @Bart: :-) I think I should have highlighted the non-SPAM posts. Would have taken a bit less time. But I'm quite proud of my SPAMrantula.

Comment: Side question: anyone know if there's a way of doing a Stack Exchange wide search with "sort by newest"? I don't know of a Google search option for that...

Comment: Just one left now.

Comment: new spam keeps coming. I'll be out of spam flags in a while, too

Comment: There's some on pretty much every site I go to. Currently browsing the Stack Exchange "All sites" page, you've got a 50% chance of noticing SPAM on the frontpage...

Comment: Yeah, I'm sitting there too. I might even write an autoregister script for me

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime for those who want to join in

Comment: damn. It's impossible to keep up if you have to register on each site

Comment: @Bart, Mat, … A word filter on http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime would make spam hunting easier, anyone up to writing some JS?

Comment: @Gilles I may, but I find visual monitoring pretty efficient. Also, you can discover some pretty interesting questions along the way, too

Comment: @JanDvorak I've had this open for a few minutes and I find it seriously distracting. If I don't look at it in real time, I need to scan back to where I left off, which leads me to open the same questions or miss some. I'd prefer a feed with just the likely spam.

Comment: right. I'll get to it, but I'm having a lunch right now, so I have to restrict myself to realtime monitoring until I'm done eating.

Comment: waters seem calm at this moment. Did something of interest happen to cause it?

Comment: I guess there are plenty of users on this game now @JanDvorak. Stuff gets blown out of the water pretty fast now.

Comment: it should still appear in the real time list, shouldn't it? I do find 404s oddly satisfying since today, though

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48159/yes-livesoccer-watch-liverpool-vs-stoke-city-live-football-barclays-pr came in less than 60s ago. _The fight is not over_! Lol. Got the best of me, I'm off for a while.

Comment: I hope we get some stats on posts/minutes and how fast the stuff got shut down.

Comment: I'm still in, but my webapp flags are thinning

Comment: Bwhaha, this starts to sound like a war movie. "I'M OUT OF WEBAPP AMMO! BACK ME UP!!"

Comment: Where's my mouse? I need a mouse!

Comment: I'm out of webapp ammo! back me up!!

Comment: Time to code while there is no more spam. First off, let's not bump a question more than once...

Comment: is there a place where to order more ammo? I've got a feeling that this is one of the cases where a sock puppet would come in legitimately handy, but no, we can't flag with less than 15 rep

Comment: spam flags should return when they're handled successfully

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48164/akshay-9540472722-escort-service-in-connaght-place-independent-delhi-female-e - hum, an ordinary spammer's trying to get through... didn't get the message that Football > Gurls

Comment: It would be brilliant if those football guys flagged that as spam @Mat.

Comment: I'm wondering whether there will be any collateral damage on [sports.se]

Comment: damn it! I'm out of battery! that will be several minutes of downtime. Totally unacceptable!

Comment: I've missed the big fight but there still a lot of them!

Comment: @Marc-Andre flag away! 11 helpful flags yet I'm not given more. Webapps needs yoou

Comment: Yep I'm there on the real-time tab watching! I've created two new accounts to flag!

Comment: @Marc-Andre did you flag through the webapps front page first?

Comment: When you are out of ammo, build a weapon factory. I'm going to code

Comment: Yes, I've check there first there was one sport spam and one ordinary spammer (call girl). The front page seems clean to me, except for one I've already flag!

Comment: good job, soldier! :-)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288602/epl-tv-liverpool-vs-stoke-city-live-live-streaming-free-hd#18288641) is a spam question with a spam answer (by a sockpuppet account). [He/she](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2691917/ali-hasan) is one of the sockpuppets.

Comment: This is the exact situation why I think moderators should be able to [handle spam network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192881).

Comment: There is new spam post on programmers, osx and unix linux

Comment: just in time for me to have returned

Comment: Let's do a campaign to outlaw all sports except test match cricket. At worse, one spam campaign every five days. Should help. Who's with me?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193656/where-to-watch-sunderland-vs-fulham-live-stream - yay! they found meta!

Comment: @Mat h... how did I miss this post?

Comment: the spam-lords should have a cyber-enema...(i.e. their computers uncomfortably inserted in an embarrassing orifice).

Comment: Sounds like a feature request for goat.SE

Comment: @Bart sounds less familiar when you actually expand the abbreviation.

Comment: Also related: [Livestream sports spam](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2448)

Comment: +1 Awesome freehand arrows! :P

Comment: (cc @JanDvorak) [They've made it to MathOverflow.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139782/watch-kick-ass-2-online-free-download-kick-ass-2-k-d)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128952/sequelwatch-kick-ass-2-online-free - still at it on TeX... ( @michaelb958 ) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128953/dexter-season-8-episode-8-watch-online-free-putlocker Well, at least it's not football anymore...

Comment: @Mat yup. download my updated script. Currently at 1.5.1

Comment: we've got an [apple.se] sighting. I repeat, we've got an [apple.se] sighting.

Comment: [One more reason to blacklist URL Shorteners!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services)

Comment: [They've broken through our lines and attacked Drupal!](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82956/full-rugbywests-tigers-vs-sydney-roost) Fall back!

Comment: Just got a Drupal, a TeX and an Ask Different within seconds.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby or, one more way to recognise the spam (if the RTQF preserved links)

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/users/3146897/user2695827?tab=accounts - they seem more eager at registering on multiple sites than earlier. Don't forget to follow the profiles!

Comment: They're now mass posting to ~20 sites

Comment: Yeah, [android.se] has started seeing this too.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**aug 19** - [tex.se](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is under attack. Yes, this is a call to arms. Keep flagging the spam posts while you can, anywhere they go. As this seems much heavier than the initial attack, I will try to notify the tex mods as well.

I have written a userscript for [the network-wide real-time feed](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) - just copy/paste into the javascript console or install as a userscript.

What it does:

- collapse posts that are bumped more than once, assuming they have already been reviewed and that spam normally doesn't get answered or edited. The set of bumped posts is persisted across sessions.
- attempt to highlight likely spam. Currently the test is very specific (few false negatives) as far as sports-related spam is concerned and very selective (none to almost none false positives).
- allow to hide questions per-site until the end of UTC day - the "cure" for "I'm out of ammo". This cannot be automated due to the same-origin policy.
- display a notification if a suspicious post appears. Clicking the notification opens the suspicious tab in a new window.

What it does not (yet):

- feature an on/off toggle. Requested by @Gilles
- collapse and/or colorise old posts properly. The data used to do this is grabbed from the web socket.
- it does not always add no-flag icon immediately. There is a race condition between the two instances of the web socket. The problem is self-repairing.
- display the no-flag icon on initial load. This should be easy to fix.
- feature a scroll lock. If the scroll lock is enabled, the scroll-locked position should be kept at one place at the screen. The lock should have a visual indicator. The lock should never be hoisted to the top.

Here it is: https://github.com/honnza/se-spam-helper/blob/master/se-spam-helper.user.js

Comment: I don't see any visible effects. Edits still come through. Chrome 27.

Comment: It would be nice to have a toggle between spam hunting mode and normal mode.

Comment: I was assuming the copy&paste/non-copy&paste action or the userscript manager action would be sufficient as a toggle. I will add a toggle, though. As for nothing being visible, there is not enough data in the websocket stream to determine if a question is edited or a new one (barring the assumption of per-site increasing IDs). Instead, I assume questions I've never seen are new ones

Comment: currently I'm debugging a per-site-per-day "i'm out of flags" hider. Then I'll sync to github and update the answer.

Comment: Can you expand on what "call to arms" means?  I think from the comments in this thread I was able to infer that, yes, we could use ordinary members to cast spam flags for the time being, but that's hard to tell from this post alone.

Comment: Note, I've made several sweeps through TeX to clean it out, and roasted about half a dozen network wide spammers subsequently.

Comment: @TimPost wow! it seems much more calm now. Thanks!

Comment: @TimPost: half a dozen is really short change compared to what we've seen this week-end. That's "tip of the iceberg"-like.

Comment: @Mat spamm*er*s, not posts. The RTQF seems very clean now. The "30 minutes without an accident" kind of clean.

Comment: @Jan: There's at least 12 different spammer accounts in my Web Apps flag page alone. I suspect yours looks similar. (Not counting the 4 accounts that are still live.) Some of the spam accounts registered profiles on several sites, but the majority did not (from what I saw). I'm glad six more got nuked, but that's not a cleansing.

Comment: @Mat I know, I looked at what happened over the weekend, this is getting super, super annoying. They (were) on almost every site in the network, I'm circling back to you shortly to get the ones that you probably haven't seen yet.

Comment: @Mat related: [Mark 12:41-44, Luke 21:2-4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2012:41-44,%20Luke%2021:2-4&version=NIV)

Comment: @Tim: http://stackexchange.com/users/3142932/user185129?tab=accounts - cross-country spammer, 2-days old account.

Comment: @Jan: inspiring. Interestingly enough, I don't think I spotted any spam on the various religiously-themed sites.

Comment: @Mat I'll add some statistical code to the spam helper

Comment: @Jan: just tested whatever version's on there right now (couldn't earlier): excellent! Even got the desktop notification thingy :-)

Comment: @Mat by the way, there seems to be a high tide on [apple.se]

Comment: T'sbin nuked. Top question on there now is about log spamming :-)

Comment: one has just arrived... and I'm out of flags

Comment: @Tim: this one's pretty impressive in terms of associations http://stackexchange.com/users/3186710/user46011?tab=accounts

Comment: @Mat the best thing is that I can just let the RTQF open in a back tab, click away notifications that come and yet I have plenty things to flag

Comment: Yep, it's perfect. Running low on flags though :-/

Comment: not yet. Though I'm drained on [apple.se] and [tex.se], I've still got ~7 flags on most other sites.

Comment: @Mat I'm still peeking occasionally for false negatives, general c... lose fodder and interesting questions. Though if I do miss some spam, it will be handled from the main site anyways, I'm sure.

Comment: @TimPost: just noticed a rather troubling behavior (http://askubuntu.com/questions/334804/watch-teen-wolf-season-3-episode-12-online-free and the other post from that same account): posted initially without links (but all the text), links ninja'd in after a few seconds...

Comment: @Mat I don't check for the presence of links since they are not present in the live feed. Also, most valid posts contain one or two links. I did notice however, that spam (and in rare cases general VLQ) loves to repeat large chunks of text within the body. I guess I could apply some rudimentary "compression" and compare the before/after sizes, but I'd need to access the full question body for that. I guess the rate limiter wouldn't like me if I did.

Comment: @Jan: yes your script caught them, but I'm guessing that evaded some of the SE filters on post submit. Was thinking about identifying repeats too, there's probably simpler/cheaper than a compression comparison.

Comment: @Mat this is my compression scheme: `while(something.changes) y.replace(/(.*?[a-z].*?)\1+/, function(...){...})`

Comment: Hmm, has something changed to the spam that the filter no longer catches, or has it really gone this quiet? No notifications for almost a day now. :s Surely there should be some football spam this afternoon. Worked brilliantly this week though. :)

Comment: @Bart did you get a disconnect in the meantime? If the websocket  fails, it doesn't get reopened. I'll add a watchdog.

Comment: @Bart updated to include an auto-refresh.

Comment: @JanDvorak That might have happened. Just caught a couple of new spam posts today. Unfortunately the F1 GP spam didn't follow the same patterns, but an addition of "prix" to the script picked that up nicely as well.

Comment: @Bart I added `watch` as a sufficient trigger. This should catch the grand prix spam.

Answer (score 10):

> **NOTICE: salesforce.SE is under attack! I'm almost of flag ammo! Please come help!** <sub>aug 22</sub>

### Doorknob's SpamHelper v2.3

*Now with spam detection and sound effects!*

I like Jan's spam helper a lot, but I personally think the question boxes are too big, so I can't see lots of posts at once. I made a little script to rectify this (just run it in the console at https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime):

```
s=document.createElement('style');s.innerHTML='.metaInfo,.siteLink,.realtime-body-summary{display:none}.question-container{padding:2px!important}#mainArea a:visited{color:#F44!important}';document.head.appendChild(s)

// Spam detection (only works in Chrome, Firefox, latest Safari,
// and latest Opera) (added in v2)
t=document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0],l=t.innerHTML;(new(window.MutationObserver||window.WebKitMutationObserver)(function(m){m.forEach(function(l){for(var i=0;i<l.addedNodes.length;i++){n=l.addedNodes[i],h=n.innerHTML;if(/<h2>[\s\S]*?\b(live|watch|vs)\W*\b[\s\S]*?<\/h2>/i.test(h)){t.innerHTML='### SPAM FOUND ###';n.style.backgroundColor='#FAA'}}})})).observe(document.getElementById('mainArea'),{childList:true});window.onfocus=function(){t.innerHTML=l}
```

I doubt it works with Jan's script (`:(`) but I find it very helpful as I can get an overview.

Here's what it looks like (click image to enlarge):

[image]

Red link means you have visited it. This is so you don't revisit a post you already flagged.

---

<s>Spam highlighting coming soon!</s> Version 2: spam highlighting added! Version 2.3: Sound effect from chat (the *ding!*) plays when spam appears - allowing me to *consistently* handle spam within seven seconds! (click to enlarge)

[image]

I had to post fake spam to test my script because no spam was coming up :P Don't worry, I deleted it instantly after I saw that it was working.

Here's how I test for spam (`h` is the text of the question):

```
if(/<h2>[\s\S]*?\b(live|watch|vs)\W*\b[\s\S]*?<\/h2>/i.test(h)){
```

Spam also changes the title of the page to `### SPAM FOUND ###`. It changes back to the old title when you look at the spam. I might make desktop notifications like Jan's script in a later version.

Here's what a wave of spam looks like:

[image]

Changelog:

- v2.3: sound effect added, slight optimizations
- v2.2: fixed bug where sometimes spam wasn't detected
- v2.1: only search title for spam detection
- v2: spam detection, fixed bug with red link bleeding.
- v1: original version.

Comment: Related: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/426/any-way-of-blocking-spam (Only 2 flag cookies left there for me too :-/)

Comment: @Mat Yep, I saw that post too. I have 2 bullets left too :( Spam highlighting is being worked on

Comment: The desktop notification think in Jan's script is what makes it great IMO, you can just leave the page in the background somewhere. I like the more quiet presentation with your script though. (There's some red bleeding onto the header and sidebar though.)

Comment: @Mat I've noticed the red bleeding. Fixed in the next update. Desktop notifications sound nice, I might do that later.

Comment: @Mat Updated :D

Comment: Hey! It highlighted **this** question in red! I'm no spammer!?!!?!? :)

Comment: @Mat Haha, err... that doesn't seem right... must test more :P

Comment: @Mat Updated again :) this time it didn't highlight it

Comment: Hum, might have been a glitch I took the new version, there's no way that would have matched this question's text. And it reappeared just now with not highlighting. Confirmed ok with new update.

Comment: @Mat I know, edits make questions reappear in the list.

Comment: You'll get yourself Q-banned there if you're not careful :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/629/discussion-between-doorknob-and-mat)

Comment: New wave of spam; the filter's working very nicely :D

Comment: With the new sound effects I can flag within 7 seconds consistently :D

Comment: Wow... trying to find real-time spam, yet a moderator gets thrashed and threatened on multiple sites by some idiot. Your script doesn't detect that one yet. ;)

Comment: @Bart Huh? Which mod? By whom? What are you referencing?

Comment: ManishEarth, mod on Physics and Chem. The real-time page was full of them. Hey, I got to use my flags... :)

Comment: @Bart Ah, I was away for a while so I missed all the fun. :P