# Flagging history doesn't show anything when the only flags being cast are spam flags

Tags: bug, spam, flag-history

Today I've helped flag a lot of spam for this: [SPAM deluge over at WebApps (and pretty much all over SE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193646/spam-deluge-over-at-webapps-and-pretty-much-all-over-se).

When I've visited my profile on WebApps to see my flag history of flag, the information about my flagging history was missing.

Note that these spam flags were my only flags on this site.

[image: screen of my profile at webapp with missing flag history]

Normally, I should have more information like when I'm looking at my Stack Overflow account.

[image: screen of my stack overflow account with my flagging history]

Is this a bug?

Comment: it may need a bit of time to catch up!

Comment: This is cached too? I suppose that almost everything on Stack Exchange is cache.

Comment: maybe it got injured in the spam-war

Comment: I see the same thing on Gamedev and TeX, where the only flags I've ever cast are spam flags (and on TeX comment flags). So I concur with the hypothesis that the sidebar info is missing when there are 0 moderator attention flags. @Damien Here I'm pretty sure this is not caching.

Comment: @Gilles yep, makes sense.  Your and Marc-Andre's hypothesis does make sense.

Comment: @Gilles That was my hypothesis too

Comment: So, this appears to remain an issue in March 2014. Will it be considered [tag:status-deferred]?

Comment: I came here to post the same thing and found this post. It remains an issue. I suspect it has something to do with lack of certain kinds of other activity, and agree with Gilles' analysis. It is certainly not "caching" of any sort, it is this way on all of my 101-rep spam-flag-only site accounts and has been for a long time.

Comment: related (possible duplicate): [If I have flagged a post, show me a “flags” link in my profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile)

Comment: Issue still exists. Needs some follow up from the devs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed now:

> [image]