# If I'm out of spam flags, tell me sooner

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-interface, rate-limiting

At the moment, suppose I see a [post that I want to flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193646/spam-deluge-over-at-webapps-and-pretty-much-all-over-se). The workflow is:

1. Open the page.
2. Click “flag”.
3. Select the flag reason.
4. Click the “flag question” button.
5. Get feedback that I've used up my flags.

Ok, so after step 2 there's a counter of my remaining flags in a corner of the flag box. I do get my feedback sooner, but it's discrete. It's easy to miss if I'm not paying attention to the flag box (which is likely when I'm flagging spam on a random succession of sites, and I want to focus on getting rid of spam with as little effort as possible).

Showing me the flag dialog is useless when I'm out of flag. Please show the “no flags remaining” popup instead of the flag dialog at step 2.

Comment: Good note. I'll incorporate that to my userscript. When do flags reset?

Comment: @Jan: 00:00 UTC

Comment: thanks. It will have to be somewhat manual, however. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Perhaps OT, but is there a reason why we can be out of spam flags? Shouldn't we get them back if they are dismissed as helpful? I'm still seeing spam on WebApps and there's nothing I can do about it. Though all my flags were helpful.

Comment: I really don't see the point of these spam posts though. Yeah it's football, but you're not part of the team's advertising division...

Comment: @ColeJohnson they're seeking views. just a pure hard advertisement currency.

Comment: @JanDvorak really? Just views? I find that hard to believe. What would be more beleivable is if they are looking for people to click the links to the sites and then install malware. Just views sounds like someone with no life.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I am only theorising. I do like your malware theory, however

Comment: @ColeJohnson Ever visit one of those sites? Seen the advertisement on them? Let's just say they wouldn't do it if it wasn't worth the effort.

Comment: @Bart no I haven't because I don't visit spam sites.

Comment: All it takes is one misspelled "flag" to send Juvenile minds like mine on a giggling spree.

Comment: @Bart - If spam flags were returned after being marked as helpful then in theory a clique of 6 users could delete every question on the site.

Comment: @MartinSmith It would be all right if this kicked in only when a moderator destroys the account. Bart, you should request that in a separate question.

Comment: @Martin I'm in. Let's start by cleaning up the Android tag on SO.