# sports-related questions appearing on SO

Tags: support

probbaly a bug somewhere, but there's a lot of sports related questions popping up on SO, getting voted down real fast and disappearing. probably a glitch in some other stackexchange site? (for example, see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473126/legia-warsaw-vs-steaua-bucharest-live-online-streaming))

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193646/spam-deluge-over-at-webapps-and-pretty-much-all-over-se

Answer (score 4):

It's a spam bot that keeps posting.

The sport posts are advertisements for a sports streaming service and the 'downvotes' are the result of the posts being flagged by users. See [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

We don't like spammers here on the Stack Exchange, and this is **not** a bug. The system is working exactly as designed.

Comment: I don't think this should be marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign], however.

Comment: I like spammers. They allow us to rep whore when we report it here. They also give us something to do during downtime. ;)