# I can't flag as fast as Spam is incomming

Tags: discussion, spam

There is a massive Spam attack running, which can be tracked here https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime with the patteren "Here is Practical Explanation about Next Life, Purpose of Human Life, philosophical/religious facts,-"

Comment: Related: [SPAM deluge over at WebApps (and pretty much all over SE)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193646/spam-deluge-over-at-webapps-and-pretty-much-all-over-se)

Comment: +1 for the realtime link. Didn't know that one.

Comment: At the moment there's nothing in the realtime thingy...can you elaborate.

Comment: You must be referring to our pal the [Supreme Lord Krishna](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19022055/464709) (10K only). I flagged two of these this morning, one on SO and the other on Programmers. Apparently there are multiple users involved.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be quiet at the moment. There have been posts over all stacksites with always the same spamcontent, 3 usernames, which did not seem to be related between the sites. I just could not flag fast enough since I had to log on, on the different sites first.

Comment: Just as an FYI, we're as aware of this as you are. Let's hope the good folks at SE will step in soon.

Comment: [Here is another one on Sports.SE](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3278/540) Now gone..

Comment: Folks on [music.se] are [actually trying to suggest more appropriate sites for this junk](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/12083). Now that's good, dedicated people :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: But but but but...but that answer should be a comment!

Comment: Ouch.. Was it spam? I just flagged one [here](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/8203/here-is-practical-explanation-about-next-life-purpose-of-human-life-philosophi)

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby, indeed. I suspect its author posted it as an answer in jest. I won't flag it, the question will not remain around long enough for it to be worth the effort :)

Comment: The attack restarted a view minutes ago ....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't want practical explanations about the purpose of human life from someone who spends his time doing… this? You should really open your mind.

*keeps reading the spam text*

**What? No coffee? No meat?** I can't get on board with this philosphy. **Activate kill switch!**

All posts gone, and they shouldn't be able to come back either.

Comment: All posts gone, and our dreams of Marshal badges with them ;)

Comment: Here's one: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/here-is-practical-explanation-about-next-life-purpose-of-human-life-philosophi

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12652/here-is-practical-explanation-about-next-life-purpose-of-human-life-philosophi

Comment: @Yannis I'd rather not say what exactly I did to prevent new ones :) Note that the examples here (thanks all!) are all from before that, I just missed them on my deletion spree.

Comment: I posted the identical question a few days ago, about the exact same spam, and was told to flag it, and not post about it here. What should someone do if they see dozens of copies of the same spam?

Comment: @user814064 For a wide-spread spam attack like that guy, posting here is fine. But you have to provide some context -- all your "question" contained was two links.

Comment: Thanks what would be the correct thing to say? This? Spam Attack Syystem-Wide please help?

Comment: [Ohh no! They found us!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198543/here-is-practical-explanation-about-next-life-purpose-of-human-life-philosophi)

Comment: Hrmph, so much for that. Thanks @M.NightDemonbobby, on it.