# Websockets are borked on the realtime question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, web-sockets, realtime-questions

When I load the [realtime question page](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime), this happens in my console:

[image]

And the list doesn't update in real time. This makes me sad. Please fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmmm, so that DNS was used after all! We did some cleanup yesterday on the stackexchange.com zone.

A build updating it to the correct `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` is going out now, should be working shortly.

Comment: Awesome, it already works. Thanks!

Comment: do I understand correctly the websocket URL has changed? Should I update my userscript?

Comment: @JanDvorak it changed some time ago, but why does it appear in a user script? We may change it at any time, hardcoding it anywhere isn't an awesome idea.

Comment: @NickCraver how should I obtain the URL, then? Or, is there a documentation of the `StackExchange` object?

Comment: @JanDvorak let me step back, why is your user script trying to access websockets in the first place? They have a very specific purpose which is already in those pages

Comment: Here is said userscript: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193646. I chose websockets over scraping the page for variety of reasons. One is that I thought it would hold more information than the page (say, a longer snippet). The other was of performance: `MutationObservers` were not well supported in web browsers back then, nor were mutation events (they also killed performance. the the MO support is better now, but I don't want to rewrite this part just because I can), and polling the page for changes felt conceptuallly wrong. Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343

Comment: @JanDvorak we have greatly improved the spam blocking since then, and are about to do another round of improvements, is this an issue anymore? Obviously from my side you can see the concern: I want to fix spam appearing for all users rather than fix a script made to hide it for a few.

Comment: @Nick on the smaller sites spam can stick for hours if not reported using such measures so I think it'll always be an issue.

Comment: @NickCraver That script helped several of us to be alerted of cross-network spam so we could go and flag even on sites we're not necessarily active on. I have plenty of accounts where my only activity is spamflags to help them out. That was a pretty useful thing IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard then any scripts performing decent automated blocking (that we currently miss) we'd certainly welcome as suggestions to improving the global spam blocking. I'm not opposed to the user script working, but that logic should also travel upstream don't you agree?

Comment: I appreciate the effort to block spam before it appears. If it makes my spam filter obsolete, I will be more than happy. So far, I do have quite a few true detections (and seems very reliable for certain persistent spammers). Do I understand correctly the spam-filter only checks high-volume sources? As for the "for all users concern", this is a tool to find stuff to flag, not a way to hide it for a single person. The latter could be just as easily accomplished by me not visiting the realtime tab ;-)

Comment: @NickCraver I do certainly agree that this should be fixed server-side. My script produces a lot of false positives, but Manish's script seems to work perfectly well. It reports screaming (all-caps titles, which are either VLQ or outright spam), phone numbers and some select keywords.

Comment: @Nick the existing scripts/bots are not blocking anything, they just report such spam in chat thus calling users who can flag as spam.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'd just update the URL for now - we *shouldn't* be changing it in the near future, it's SSL/TLS secured and has been moved to a service URL rather than a location one as we prep to have more data centers online. If there's a common case we're missing though, certainly post it as a meta question so we can tackle it before it goes to any users.

Comment: @Jan the Smoke Detector also got his share of false positives, e.g. error numbers in code which appear as phone numbers to the script.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have a different point of view here. Keep in mind there's a *lot* you don't see that never makes it through the spam filters, hundreds of thousands of posts a day currently.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yet I'm certainly for adding screaming as an auto-blocking VLQ heuristic.

Comment: @NickCraver which is a great thing, indeed. And I'm more than determined that hunt down the few that made it through the sieve, even if I'm unnecessarily alerted of multiple false positives. Autoflag heuristics can be much more strict than autoblock heuristics. Perhaps some of these heuristics should be fed to the existing VLQ queue (another side effect is that the audits would look more realistic)?

Comment: @JanDvorak possibly VLQ, or applied outright - ones that are very high confidence send to team@stackexchange.com and we'll run them over all the data and see what we can do.  Spam is a constant battle, we're not going to refuse any help on the matter - and we very much appreciate what you guys are already doing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We currently have a pull to kinda sorta fix Smoke Detector... not sure if it'll help or not with numbers.