# Let me know if an answer is deleted while I am viewing it

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-answers

Just now I was writing a comment explaining some of the inner workings of jQuery to someone who was doing something like this in an answer:

```
$("li").each(function(){ $(this).click(function(){ var id = $(this).attr("id"); }); });
```

Sorry for hurting your eyes with that, but it is pretty much verbatim.

Clearly there is a lot going on there that would warrant some explanation to the poster because I think they misunderstood some aspects. So I set out posting a comment, it turned out to be 700 characters long (as in I was going to have to cut half, post, and then post a second one). I was trying to help, I even made sure to be cordial.

Unfortunately, as I clicked the post comment button, I was informed the post was deleted. There was really no where to go from there.

When a post is edited and I am looking at it, I see a "this answer has been edited" notification.

**Please also include a "this answer has been deleted" notification.**

Comment: I agree, we do this for answering and editing deleted questions, why not on comments for answers?

Comment: inb4 this gets ignored by the powers to be, bountied multiple times and finally solved by some hacky userscript

Comment: I might as well cut it short and write a userscript right away; should I go ahead already?

Comment: @Jan yes please.