# What is this "time this post deletion" thingy?

Tags: support

I came across a newly-asked question today. Someone had flagged the post as a possible duplicate, and I agreed with them. After I was done flagging, this happened:

> [image]

I checked the box, but nothing happened. After refreshing the page, it was gone.

- What is it?
- Why is it there?
- Should it be there?

Comment: Looks like a shiny Dev thing. If you push it, it's not my fault :P

Comment: @Undo I did, but nothing happened.

Comment: Was this in the 10k queue?

Comment: @Undo I don't know. I only have ~1500 rep.

Comment: Looks like this comes from an extension (http://pastie.org/pastes/8660385)

Comment: @Mat Right. Duh. I have that script installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it results from a custom script. It is therefore mostly unrelated to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As pointed out by Mat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220159/what-is-this-time-this-post-deletion-thingy#comment713404_220159), this comes from [a script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214833/238586) I stupidly forgot I had installed. I still have no idea what is does, though.