# Can fire burn through a question page if the question has been deleted?

Tags: feature-request, fun

Sometimes, I find myself looking at a question, only to find out that the question has actually been deleted since the page loaded.

So, I was thinking, wouldn't it be *cool* if the page would spectacularly catch on fire once it was deleted (without refreshing). Then I would *definitely* know that the post was deleted, and wouldn't try to take an action on the post thinking it still existed. This would be a universal feature across all sites, with fire possibly changing based on the theme of each site. Here's some mockups:

Mine:
[image: My Mockup]

Animusion's [suggestion](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2293283#2293283):
[image: via Animusion]

Of course, it would have to be animated.

If anyone has their own fire mockups for this feature, I would encourage that they be added to this question. (Or link in a comment)

Comment: Is this for all sites or solely for MSE?

Comment: @bluefeet All sites. However MSE might want a more bluish fire...

Comment: Wait... it *is* Friday, isn't it?

Comment: I like the crayon one...

Comment: related: [New background for deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211478/165773)

Comment: Oh! Oh! It could turn into the side of a 3D cube and spin away! Or a circle wipe!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notify instantly when a post is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172267/notify-instantly-when-a-post-is-deleted)

Comment: @JanDvorak But I'm proposing _fire_

Comment: @JanDvorak no it's not a dupe, you missed the [meta-tag:fun] tag here. He's not really asking to get instant notification.

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh. In which case, I heartily disagree with this request.

Comment: @Jan of course, but looks like our dear Mr. Claus doesn't really care and it's his full right. He's also not asking to **really add such a thing**, just to get cool ideas, like he did already.

Answer (score 16):

http://jsfiddle.net/r470296o/1/embedded/result/

Click to start animation. Feel free to fork.

Comment: eh, very nice!!

Comment: Doesn't work on touchscreen devices

Comment: @SantaClaus Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Fire is too *[close voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue)* related.

Here is something more *[404](https://stackapps.com/404)* related: http://jsfiddle.net/fb6ub4jq/2/embedded/result/

Comment: NSFW warning!!!

Comment: Please don't click on that link. Your life will never be the same...