# Why does this question still show an expired bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252685/162102) had a bounty that was posted 8 days ago.  Its grace period expired earlier today (according to the revision history), and in fact the question does not show a bounty on the front page:

[image: front page snippet]

However, it does still show a bounty notice -- one that even says the grace period has expired -- on the question:

[image: bounty notice in question]

Should I blame caching?  I would if the notice showed in both places (question and front page).

Comment: It's gone ....:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system does not automatically remove the bounty and post notice from a question the moment it expires. Like with many other things on the network, there is a process that runs every so often that will eventually remove it. This is also the process that will inevitably decide if half the bounty should be automatically awarded to an answer on the question too.

The notice at this point is basically saying that both the bounty and the grace period have expired, and the bounty is pending automatic awarding and removal by the system.

Comment: Oh, it's a "resolution pending" notice.  Thanks.  (Should it say that instead of "grace period expired"?)